# How much Maelstrom does the Elemental Shaman mastery give?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Looking at the [Elemental Shaman mastery](https://www.wowhead.com/spell=168534/mastery-elemental-overload) in World of warcraft it states that:

> Your Lightning Bolt, and Chain Lightning casts have a 15.0% chance to trigger a second cast on the same target for 85% of normal damage and generates less Maelstrom.

How much Maelstrom is generated on each overload for lightning bolt and chain lightning, per target hit?

With the talent "High Voltage" that has a 50% chance of normal to proc a 3rd overload, will this give the same amount of Maelstrom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was initially under the impression that maelstrom generated from overload procs was 50% for all spells. However, I tested this on the training dummies in Dazar'alor and found this is not the case.

The following test results are from patch 8.0.1 (October 9th, 2018):

- **Lightning bolt** overload and high voltage procs generate **3 maelstrom** (37.5% of base).
- **Chain lightning** overload and high voltage procs generate **2 maelstrom** (50% of base).
- **Lava burst** overload procs generate **4 maelstrom** (40% of base).

The maelstrom granted is different for each spell, which explains why the mastery description is vaguely worded.

Comment: Ele main here, this is correct. And the High Voltage Overload gives that 50% of normal again.

Comment: @SaintWacko I did some testing today and found that only chain lightning grants 50% of base. Do you see the same results I have seen in my updated answer?

Comment: I've searched my combat logs and yes, only CL grants 50%. Your numbers are correct.

Comment: Oh, interesting! I wonder when that changed...